# When I click "enable macros" on my PowerPoint presentation, I get an error saying controls can't be activated. They're not registered on this computer

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

I recently received a new Mac computer for work. I regularly use files which have macros built in. I am not the creator of these files/macros and am not an expert in this area.

For one of my files, each time I open it and click "enable macros" I get an error:

> Some controls on this presentation can't be activated. They might not be registered on this computer.

I have confirmed that the macros are functioning properly on the Windows machines of my colleagues. I have also tried a few other macro-enabled files on my Mac which also seem to be functioning properly. Clearly there is some issue with this one file.

I have entered into Visual Basic Editor and confirmed that the code is there. It has been transferred properly via cloud transfer from my old PC to my new Mac.

Comment: Sounds like the file has some activex controls which may not work on your Mac or at least may need to installed

Comment: Tim's on the right track. The error message indicates the presence of references to ActiveX controls. They can only be used in Windows, they are not supported in Office for Mac.